# Clause Select in Datatable

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, datatables

**I'm trying to do some Selects in a Datatable**, but I am having some problems because I have values in some cells like this: 'COX-12-3SCS4CSCH

This value has **'** and **-**

I tried to do this select but doesn't work:

```
string expression = "Nivel='" + lvfin + "' AND [Nivel " + lvfin + "]='" + codActual + "'";
DataRow[] results = DataTable.Select(expression);
```

*lvfin* contains for example 0 and *codActual* contains 'COX-12-3SCS4CSCH

And I get this error:

> Missing operand after operator 'COX'

What is the problem here?

Comment: It is not clear the second part of the condition. Do you have a field named _[Nivel 'COX-12-3SCS4CSCH]_ ? It seems that you mix the field name with the value that you are looking for.

Comment: I have a field Name called Nivel 0, for example, and his value is 'COX-12-3SCS4CSCH .

Comment: I do not know how to do it in c#, but when I 've had same problem in VBA, I replace single `'` with `''`, and it works like a charm for me. So sometihing like `Replace(codActual,"'","''")` may help

Comment: It looks like the code is interpreting the dash as a minus sign.  I think @GetData solution of putting double quotes around the operand instead of single quotes may work.

Answer (score 0):

If your field name is `Nivel 0` then you need to add that zero to the constant string "Nivel" and enclose the whole field name into square brackets to form the correct field name used in the first condition, then, if the value that you search contains a single quote, then you need to double it. All this is necessary to avoid confusing the parser when you use a single quote as delimiter for string values or your field names contains spaces.

So you should write (line by line for clarity but could be written in a single line):

```
string fieldName = "Nivel " + lvfin.ToString();
string searchValue = codActual.Replace("'", "''");
string expression = $"[{fieldName}]='{searchValue}'";
DataRow[] results = DataTable.Select(expression);
```